# Bootstrap - Progress Indicator

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that uses Bootstrap 3. I am trying to make a responsive progress indicator. The indicator has between three and five steps. Each step shows an icon, the step name, and the step status. When on mobile, I'm trying to make it look like this:

```
o  Step 1
|  completed monday
|
o  Step 2
|  in progress
|
o  Step 3
   to be done
```

When the screen appears on anything other than a phone, I'm trying to show it like this:

```
        o----------------o---------------o
     Step 1            step 2          step 3
completed Monday     in progress     to be done
```

In an effort to create this I current have the following code, which can be seen in [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/AB5Ekgdp02).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        Step 1<br>
          <span class="text-muted">completed monday</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i>
        Step 2<br>
        <span class="text-muted">in progress</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
        <span class="text-muted">to be done</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to get the line between the circles. Is there a way to do this with bootstrap or CSS? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used basic `table` control on your HTML code `(horizontal)`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        <span>-----------------------------</span>
        <br>
        Step 1
        <br>
          <span class="text-muted">completed monday</span>
      </li>
          </td>
          <td>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i>
        <span>-----------------------------</span>
        <br>
        Step 2<br>
        <span class="text-muted">in progress</span>
      </li>
          </td>
          <td>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><br>

        Step 3<br>
        <span class="text-muted">to be done</span>

      </li>
          </td>
         </tr> 
      </table>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Vertical version:**

CSS:

```
.vertical_line{height:150px; width:1px;background:#000; margin-left:5px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        Step 1 &nbsp; -
          <span class="text-muted">completed monday</span>
        <div class="vertical_line"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i>
        Step 2 &nbsp; -
        <span class="text-muted">in progress</span>
        <div class="vertical_line"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
        <span class="text-muted">to be done</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also change the horizontal to have a CSS like the vertical version.

Comment: Will this go vertical? Also, is there a way to use a solid line instead of the dashes (------)?

Comment: @ZachTempleton This is designed to stay horizontal. I didn't realise you wanted vertical. Change the dash code with solid line ASCII code which is "**&#151;**"

Comment: @ZachTempleton You need to be more specific about the way how it looks. Vertical? There are 2 answers here and both coded to made your code horizontal.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. In the question, I showed the progress indicator in both vertical and horizontal views.

Comment: @ZachTempleton See above edit. If it works for your needs, please upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used @apollo's solution and made simple change on `ul` class.

I have use `<ul class="list-inline">` instead of `<ul class="list-unstyled">`

Created [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yjLkntv/2/) for you.

Comment: Will this go vertical? Also, is there a way to use a solid line instead of the dashes (------)?

Comment: for solid line you need to make little change in you code.
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yjLkntv/5/) 
for vertical you need to write different code. I have made both in above link!